# How to import and export content in HIPPO CMS

Tags: hippocms

Do we have provision in HIPPO CMS where I can export the content and documents from one environment and import it onto another environment? I am using HIPPO CMS 7.9.3 community edition and deployed it on Apache tomcat 7

Answer (score 1):

there are a number of tools, depending on your use case. Can you tell us more about what you are trying to do?

You can manually import and export content via the console [1].

You may want to take advantage of our enterprise replication module if that fits your use case [2].

You can also write a custom application that uses the JCR API or a REST interface. It really depends on what you are trying to do.

Hope this helps!

[1] - http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/content-repository/enhanced-xml-import.html

[2] - http://www.onehippo.org/library/enterprise/enterprise-features/replication/replication-overview.html

Comment: Actually I have a testing environment where i create user and document's and add images and other assets. Then after testing and getting approval I have to move these user's,document's,images,assets to Production environment. I am using Apache Tomcat server,Eclipse IDE. How can i do it from cms console?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it from the Hippo console. To me, it looks like the tools William suggested is the only way out... But I'll be pleased if you prove me wrong!

Comment: This would be better off as a comment on the other answer.